# значение переменной из ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как при клике по ссылке получить значение page?

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li class="control">
            <a href="katalog?page=3">Пред.</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="katalog?page=2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="katalog?page=3">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>                   
</div>
```

Comment: И отменить переход?

Comment: нет, просто вывести значение

Comment: произойдет переход, куда выводить значение?

Comment: блин, точно, тогда прервать переход и может быть alert

Comment: ну в общем-то Вам уже ответили